# Tax query: exclude posts if ONLY a certain term is applicable

Tags: tax-query

Say I have this tax query:

```php
function add_tax_query( $args, $atts ) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'term-that-excludes' ),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ),
    );
    return $args;
}
```

Which will exclude all posts (in this case 'products') from the query on which the term `term-that-excludes` is used for the `product_cat` taxonomy. I want to adapt this so that it **only** excludes products whose `product_cat` taxonomy has **only** the term `term-that-excludes`. Whenever a term is added to the taxonomy of the product, it should be collected by the query.

Is that possible?